# Prove energy preservation of implicit midpoint method.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, proof-writing, numerical-methods, physics

I am using the Runge Kutta implicit midpoint method
$$m_{n+1}=m_n + \frac{h}{2}(\frac{m_n + m_{n+1}}{2} \times (T^{-1}\frac{m_n + m_{n+1}}{2}).$$
To solve a free rigid body problem, where $T$ is the diagonal inertia tensor, $m(t)$ is the angular momentum and $h$ is the step size.

This method supposedly preserves the energy and momentum, i.e. it holds that
$$m_{n+1}^T m_{n+1}=m_n^Tm_n$$
and
$$\frac{1}{2}m_{n+1}^T(T^{-1}m_{n+1})=\frac{1}{2}m_n^T(T^{-1}m_n).$$
How can one go about proving these properties? I am thinking i should take an induction approach, but I am struggling to get started.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use that
$$
a^Ta-b^Tb=(a-b)^T(a+b).
$$
And of course that $u^T(u\times v)=\det([u,u,v])=0$.